# Split load between servers using MySQL MyISAM

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have some data that needs processing and would like to split the workload between servers.

I have:

1. Operation queue table where the operation is selected.
2. User table.
3. Queue users that connects users to queue.
4. Logs for when the operation has finished for a given user.

Right now I have a service that run one query to get the queued data and opens a thread for each.

That thread goes through the users 10 at a time as soon as one ends the next one gets in and so on until it's finished.

I want to add another server in play that will take some of the load so everything finishes faster as right now it takes half a day and that is just too much.

How would I get the two servers working together without risk of duplication?

So far I thought of the following:

1. Modify the service to lock for read, select the no of users it needs (10 at first 1 after).
2. Insert into the log so nobody else selects those users.
3. Unlock and let the threads process the data and update the log once done.

Would this work?

Is there another, better way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple sessions can hold a `READ` lock for a specific table, so that's not going to help you in this case.

In both servers, when checking for work. lock the appropriate table with `WRITE` like this:

```
LOCK TABLE queue_table WRITE
```

Use `LOCK TABLES ...` to lock more than one table. Always make sure you lock the tables in the same order.

As long as both servers are doing this before they start grabbing work, then it serializes the operation. While one server has the lock, the other will wait.

Then, do whatever you need to do to mark the queues as being processed so that the other server doesn't grab them, then release the lock.

With MyISAM, it's not quite as granular or scalable as the options you have with InnoDB.

Comment: Unfortunately for me I have to write a few rows / day but read a shitload and performance matters a lot so MyISAM it is.

Comment: So the write lock will prevent others from doing anything but allow the locker to do anything?

Comment: @tntu, a read lock will block a write lock, but not another read lock.